# sscanf(str1, "%s %d %f", str2,&num,&float1) producing unexpected results

Tags: c, input, scanf

Using the included libraries, how do I separate a string containing a name, age, and rate, from the input from fgets stored in an array?

I need to modify the string, age, and format the rate to show 3 decimal places. After that, I need to store the new result of these variables in a single char array. This is what I have so far. I don't know what is causing sscanf() to give me the unexpected results or how to fix it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 10
#define SIZE2 40

int main(){
char input[SIZE2]={};
char name[SIZE]={};
int age = 0;
float rate = 0;

printf("Enter name, age and rate (exit to quit): ");
fgets(input, SIZE2, stdin);

sscanf(input,"%s %d %f", name, &age, &rate);

printf("%s %d %.3f",name, &age, &rate);

return 0;
}
```

The name is displayed properly, but the age is some random large number and the rate is displayed as 0.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the address of operator (&) in printf("%s %d %.3f",name, &age, &rate); like 
printf("%s %d %.3f",name, age, rate);

When you put & operator in printf() It prints the address of the variable

---

But why does scanf() require the & operator?

Let us see with a example:

```
int main()
{
 int *ad,var;
 ad=&var;
 *ad=10;
 printf("%d",var);
 return 0;
}
```

it will prints 10

let see another Example with function:

```
void sum(int *sum,int a,int b)

int main()
{
 int a=10,b=10,c;
 sum(&c,a,b);
 printf("%d",c);
 return 0;
} 

void sum(int *sum,int a,int b)
{
 *sum=a+b;
}
```

It will prints 20

So,If you want to modify a variable in function You would pass the variable by reference

So,scanf() needs & of operator to get the address of variable

Comment: Thank you. Removing the & operator in printf and in my sprintf fixed the output issue. Seems like sscanf() was working properly.

Comment: But why does scanf() require the & operator?

Comment: ....because it is expected to modify the variables..  The values are useless - it must have their addresses so that it can load the vars with new values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return value of sscanf to see if it was able to find and parse the things you specified in the format string.  You should also limit the size of strings extracted into fixed size buffers so as to not overflow the buffer.  So you want something like

```
while(true) {
    printf("Enter name, age and rate (exit to quit): ");
    if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == 0) {
        // error or eof on the input
        exit(0); }
    if (sscanf(input,"%9s%d%f", name, &age, &rate) == 3)
        break;  // ok
    printf("I didn't understand that input\n");
}
printf("%s %d %.3f",name, age, rate);
```

Comment: Fixed size buffers? Why would size 40 (SIZE2) be an issue in my code?

Comment: name is only 10 bytes -- if the input name is longer than this, the buffer will overrun.