# How to use fgets and sscanf for file reading and writing in C using FILE pointer

Tags: c, file, io, c89

I am confused on how I would use `fgets`/`sscanf` combo in order to read and write a file that was opened.

I know that we use the FILE pointer to use `fopen` and 'w' or 'r' to a file, but then how would we go line by line without using `fscanf` in order to do this?

```
FILE *ptr;
ptr = fopen("input.txt", "r");
```

Then what would we do after this?

Comment: Two steps. 1. Use fgets. 2. Use sscanf. In that order. This will give you data on one line. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/q/58211580/2410359